# Bootstrap padding on inner borders but not edge of browser

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new at bootstrap and trying to place a simple grid of images on the webpage.  I'd like borders between the images but NOT the edges of the browser.  By default bootstrap puts padding on all 4 sides of the col-md elements.

I cant 'hardcode' the padding since the cells change position when the browser size changes according the responsive design.  Is there a way for bootstrap to automatically only add padding to the insides?

**HTML**

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">

            <img src="~/Content/images/saucer.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="~/Content/images/metalbranch.jpg" />

        </div>
    </div>

<div class="row" >
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="~/Content/images/moon.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="~/Content/images/peacockOnWood.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="~/Content/images/appleGlass.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="~/Content/images/pianoKeysNecklace.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <img src="~/Content/images/treeWithNecklace.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <img src="~/Content/images/gridOfCorks.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="~/Content/images/trees.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.col-md-4 img, .col-md-8 img {
    width:100%;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here : http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works

So it should be something like :

```
<div class='container'>
<div class='row'>
<ul>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
</ul>
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like this article says how to put borders on the edge of browser.  I do not want borders on the edge of the browser. (while having borders between columns)

Comment: That's exactly what class='rows' does. Remove the padding on the outer edges.

Comment: Ok sorry I didn't read the article thoroughly enough.  Looks very informative.  I'll come back to it next time I'm using bootstrap.  Thanks.